# What is causing 'Custom build for...exited with code 1' error when using Flutter for Windows app development?

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3071 (message):
The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
robustness issue.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:4167 (_ep_add_download_command)
CMakeLists.txt:9 (ExternalProject_Add)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pluto_grid-6.0.4/lib/src/widgets/pluto_scrollbar.dart(493,39): error G036AE10F: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pluto_grid-6.0.4/lib/src/widgets/pluto_scrollbar.dart(511,39): error G036AE10F: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(234,9): error G5FE39F1E: Type 'ui.ViewConfiguration' not found. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(241,3): error G5FE39F1E: Type 'ui.ViewConfiguration' not found. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(174,27): error G311314CC: Method not found: 'ViewConfiguration'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(173,7): error GC6690633: No named parameter with the name 'window'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(232,3): error GB23DA612: The superclass, 'ui.FlutterView', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart(234,12): error G6A1FD7CD: 'ViewConfiguration' isn't a type. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/fonts/font.dart(47,15): error GDC3DF8B3: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:printing/src/fonts/manifest.dart'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/screenshot-1.3.0/lib/screenshot.dart(160,7): error GC6690633: No named parameter with the name 'window'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/qr_flutter-4.1.0/lib/src/qr_painter.dart(114,8): error G5FE39F1E: Type 'QrImage' not found. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/qr_flutter-4.1.0/lib/src/qr_painter.dart(114,8): error G5641BFAA: 'QrImage' isn't a type. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/qr_flutter-4.1.0/lib/src/qr_painter.dart(156,16): error GE5CFE876: The method 'QrImage' isn't defined for the class 'QrPainter'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/Flutter_Pinput-2c198e46e1fa18a15d4667aa2d939bcbb04c7c39/lib/src/widgets/_pinput_selection_gesture_detector_builder.dart(20,39): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_PinputSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDoubleTapDown' has type 'TapDownDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragDownDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDoubleTapDown'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/Flutter_Pinput-2c198e46e1fa18a15d4667aa2d939bcbb04c7c39/lib/src/widgets/_pinput_selection_gesture_detector_builder.dart(27,35): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_PinputSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp' has type 'TapUpDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragUpDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/Flutter_Pinput-2c198e46e1fa18a15d4667aa2d939bcbb04c7c39/lib/src/widgets/_pinput_selection_gesture_detector_builder.dart(28,25): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'TapUpDetails' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TapDragUpDetails'. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\CMakeFiles\2d94be21d12b969ef228ad8a1e224996\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\CMakeFiles\8444c9888fde3357a1864f3c274dfabd\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\smart_masjid new\smasjid_client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.

When i was working with the project , the flutter asked to upgrade the flutter, then i updated the pub upgrade dependencies of the package in the flutter and also run the flutter upgarde, After Flutter upgrade, then i run the code , then it shows the Error which i was attached in the problems, please give me solution for this Error

Comment: Could you update your question to have proper formatting on the console text output part? Also you can fix the `DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP` warning by adding `cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)` to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the package was broken with flutter 3.10 but it has been fixed now:

https://github.com/SachinGanesh/screenshot/issues/139

Simply update your pubspec.yaml to 2.1.0

```
  screenshot: ^2.1.0
```